# Refresh newsfeed when scroll down, browser

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, browser

I'm making a website where there is going to be a newsfeed. Facebook got this function in the newsfeed that it loads more/older news when you scroll down. How can i make this on my website? I didnt find any places where this was explaned, if there is a website where this is explaned, please post it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily achieved by using JavaScript.

Have a look [there](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/).

This question also appeared on StackOverflow more than once. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237555/jquery-load-content-when-scroll-to-bottom-100px-of-page-multiple-events-fired) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900744/auto-load-content-on-scroll-down).

Answer (score 0):

you can search google for "Infinit scroll"
There are a lot of jQuery plugins for instance.

I use jquery-endless-scroll

https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll

Hope it helps